# How to get the difference of matrixes without repetitions removed

Tags: matlab

The function `setdiff(A,B,'rows')` is used to return the set of rows that are in A but not B, with repetitions removed.

Is there any way to do it **without** removing the repetitions?
Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`ismember`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/ismember.html) instead of `setdiff`, to find all the rows of `B` that appear in `A`.

Because you want only those that NOT appear in `A`, use the `~` sign, and finally take all `A` rows in these rows indices:

```
A =

     1     2     3
     4     5     6
     1     2     3
     7     8     9

B =

     4     5     6

C=A(~ismember(A,B,'rows'),:)

C =

     1     2     3
     1     2     3
     7     8     9
```